# Updating a list of attributes of item

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I am developing a quiz-based application on AWS using the serverless framework through AWS Amplify. The database used for this application is DynamoDB.

I am trying to store a list of user answers as a record in the database. Right now, I have my partition key (named "type") as `quizDraftAnswers_{user-id}`, so I can quickly retrieve the records based on a user's ID. I also have a sort key (named "id") as `category_{category-id}#subCategory_{subcategory-id}`.  The quiz I am creating has questions broken into categories and subcategories.  In order to more quickly retrieve the data, I thought this would be the best way to designed the sort key.

The record then has a `questions` attribute as a type List.  This attribute contains the list of question ID's and their answer in a Map.

This is an example of the data structure:

```
{
  "id": "category_89#subCategory_90",
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": "101",
      "answerId": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "102",
      "answerId": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "103",
      "answerId": "5"
    },
    {
      "id": "104",
      "answerId": "3"
    }
  ],
  "type": "quizDraftAnswers_74527"
}
```

I created an API that sends the `userId`, `category`, `subCategory`, `questionId`, and `answerId`, to a Lambda function which executes some NodeJS dynamo code.

The issue I am having with DynamoDB is, how would I go about updating the questions list?

For example, if this is the first question that a user answers, how would I go about creating the initial record (`id`, `type`, `question[]` containing a Map with an `id` and `answerId`)?  How would I add a new answer to the end of the questions list?  If the user changes their answer, how would I update it in the questions list?

This is the Lambda function I have so far:

```
exports.updateAnswer = (employeeId, categoryId, subCategoryId, questionId, answerId) =>
  new Promise(async resolve => {
    const params = {
      TableName: tableName,
      Key: {
        type: `quizDraftAnswers_${employeeId}`,
        id: `category_${categoryId}#subCategory_${subCategoryId}`
      },
      UpdateExpression: `SET #questions[].:id = :value`,
      ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#questions': 'questions'
      },
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':question': questionId,
        ':value': answerId
      }
    };

    dynamodb.update(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        resolve({ error: true, message: err });
      } else {
        resolve({ error: false, items: data.Items });
      }
    });
  });
```

The Update Expression is what I can't seem to figure out.  I've tried many different variations but always end up with some sort of error.  I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for the proper way to write this code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `list_append` function to append new elements to the list. More about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.Modifying.UpdateExpressions.SET) (**Appending Elements to a List** section)

So your parameters would look like this

```
const params = {
  TableName: tableName,
  Key: {
    type: `quizDraftAnswers_${employeeId}`,
    id: `category_${categoryId}#subCategory_${subCategoryId}`
  },
  UpdateExpression: `SET #questions = list_append(if_not_exists(#questions, :empty_list), :value)`,
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#questions': 'questions'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':empty_list': [],
    ':question': questionId,
    ':value': answerId
  }
};
```

As name suggests, `if_not_exists` function checks if the list is already present. If it's not simply add an empty list `[]` else append the new value to existing list.

Comment: How would this handle updates/changes to a users answer? If a user changed their answer, how does this only update that question?